Failed to put system to sleep - freezing fails due to NFS kernel thread failing to freeze
System:
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
Background
Before going into suspend, user space processes and (some) kernel threads get frozen. If the freezing fails, it will either be due to a user space process or a kernel thread failing to freeze.
To freeze a user space process, the kernel sends it a signal that is handled automatically and, once received, cannot be ignored. If, however, the process is in the uninterruptible sleep state (e.g. waiting for I/O that cannot complete due to the device being unavailable), it will not receive the signal straight away. If this delay lasts longer than 20s (=default freeze timeout, see /sys/power/pm_freeze_timeout (in miliseconds)), the freezing will fail.
What is causing the issue:
The log & MEGS points to a NFS kernel thread that refuses to freeze.
NFS have been historically known for causing issues like that.
What I have tried:
ps kill -9 PROCESS

It does not kill the frozen process
systemctl stop autofs

or
systemctl stop nfs-kernel-server

Allow the the system to enter into SLEEP / SUSPEND state. But the frozen process are back upon starting either service back !!!
ERROR message
[   43.579170] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.004 seconds (9 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[   43.579219] task:lockd           state:I stack:    0 pid: 1979 ppid:     2 flags:0x00004000

Question:
How can I "unfreeze / unlock" these process ?
DMSG


ps aux



We need to see the messages leading up to your Failed to put system to sleep message. Suspend to RAM requires a modern CPU. Hibernation requires a RAM-sized, contiguous, swap area. Investigate with free, swapon, filefrag

Do you have any nfs file systems mounted?

No nfs was mounted at the time. I am using AUTOFS with a short timeout but the server was not running...I suspect the nfs locked process was linked to the down nfs server. I will re-test today making sure the nfs server is up while restarting the autofs service on the client where the sleep was broken.

There seems to be a bug with the kernel 5.15.0-118, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2076576
Using the previous version 117 works for me.

I had this problem start today I guess after unknowingly updating to kernel 5.15.0-118, A comment on the bug says unmounting all shares allows suspend but that's not the case for me, still a problem with or without any nfs mounts. Workaround for me is to sudo service nfs-server stop before doing a suspend.

Ok Thanks...from this bug report: "The fix has been commit to the jammy kernel. It should be available in Ubuntu version Ubuntu-5.15.0-121.131, or later."

I encountered this problem a few days ago on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Server Version, and after discovering that it was NFS causing it is when I came across this thread.
The solution for me has been to use the "Alternate answer using systemd" in this thread:
How to run a script before suspend?
Create a file with the following and make it executable:
sudo touch /lib/systemd/system-sleep/my_script.sh
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/my_script.sh

Edit the file:
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/my_script.sh

Paste the following text and use Ctrl+o to save then Ctrl+x to exit:
#!/bin/bash

case $1/$2 in
    pre/*)
    # commands to be executed before suspend, hibernate, etc. goes below
    sudo systemctl stop nfs-kernel-server
    ;;
    post/*)
    # commands to be executed on wake, resume, etc. goes below
    sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
    ;;
esac

And bingo in my case the nfs server is stopped and restarted automatically whenever the system is suspended and awoken, and I no longer have the freezing issue.

Thanks Alan for the work-around solution. Just wondering how I will remember to change this back when the kernel will fix the problem ? Is there a simple way to add to the scrip a kernel version test and send a desktop notification as a reminder to check if this is still required ?

this doesnt seem to work for me. even running the systemctl stop command manually prior to trying to put the laptop to sleep causes it to freeze for 20 seconds and then fail to go to sleep
